# Appkit / Quartz / CG Nesting NSTextView within a custom view correctly

Tags: cocoa, swift, quartz-graphics, appkit, drawing2d

Trying to teach myself how to do custom drawing in OS X. I am trying to nest a NSTextView within a NSView.

[image: Got top, want bottom]

I can't seem to figure out the step I am missing to get the `NSTextView` to behave as if it wasn't embedded in another custom view (I.e., text should begin redering from top-left in the frame provided to the `NSTextView`, left-to-right and top-to-bottom).

```
import Cocoa
import AppKit
import XCPlayground

class MyView : NSView {
    let lipsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

    override init(frame: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame:frame)
        self.wantsLayer = true
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)

        let grey = NSColor.grayColor()
        self.layer?.backgroundColor = grey.CGColor

        let boundaryRect = NSInsetRect(dirtyRect, 10, 10)
        let textRect = NSInsetRect(boundaryRect, 10, 10)

        let path = NSBezierPath(roundedRect: boundaryRect, xRadius: 5, yRadius: 5)
        path.stroke()


        let text = NSTextView(frame: textRect)

        text.backgroundColor = grey
        text.insertText(lipsum)

        text.drawRect(textRect)
    }
}

var frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400)

let myView = MyView(frame: frame)

let textView = NSTextView(frame:frame)
textView.insertText(myView.lipsum)

XCPShowView("my view", myView)
XCPShowView("text view", textView)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't actually embedded the `text` view inside the parent view. You can do that with `addSubview()`.

```
    let text = NSTextView(frame: textRect)

    text.backgroundColor = grey
    text.insertText(lipsum)

    self.addSubview(text) // <---------
}
```

Comment: Yep that did it. How simple. Learn-by-doing does have it's downsides ;). Now I don't even have to call draw on the child.